# Mysql regex match parentheses characters on beginning or end of the string

Tags: mysql, regex

I'd like to match '(' character on the beginning,  or ')' character at the end of the string. I tried theese (beginning of the string), but nothing works:

```
mysql> SELECT '(aaa' REGEXP '[[:<:]]\\(aaa';
+-------------------------------+
| '(aaa' REGEXP '[[:<:]]\\(aaa' |
+-------------------------------+
|                             0 |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT '(aaa' REGEXP '[[:<:]][(]aaa';
+-------------------------------+
| '(aaa' REGEXP '[[:<:]][(]aaa' |
+-------------------------------+
|                             0 |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Shouldn't using regex anchors , `^`, and `$` work to anchor the selection to the beginning or end of a string? For example `^\(` and `\)$` could be combined to form `(^\(|\)$)` This would match and capture opening parens at the beginning of a string and closing parens at the end of a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to use a regular expression here, as the `LIKE` operator should be sufficient:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE col LIKE '(%' OR col LIKE '%)'
```